# I have corrupted app pages, how to I remove them?

Tags: facebook

I started a developing an app back in ~2009. It seems somehow there are 7 copies of the app I started developing. I'd love to delete all of them, but none of the 7 copies will load a dashboard page... you know... the dashboard page with the "delete" button. How should I proceed to remove these apps?

I get an HTTP500 from Facebook's servers via each link.

Comment: _“I get an HTTP500 from Facebook's servers via each link.”_ – then go open a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Wow, that's so obvious I'm sorry I didn't think of it. Duh... I should mention the last time I looked into this FB didn't have a bug reporting mechanism yet, so maybe not totally my fault? Anyway thanks. I did just that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I reported this to Facebook as a bug mid Monday. I gave them my personal info so they could see my exact data. They were able to reproduce the "bug" and confirmed to me that something was wrong right away (within hours). Just now (mid Friday) I got a message stating essentially, "yeah, some system somewhere messed up when creating your apps, so they got made in a broken state. We manually deleted them for you." So while there may or may not still be a bug out there, my problem was solved in ~4 working days by reporting it directly as a bug.